# Connect to database using sql server remotely

Tags: sql, sql-server, connection

I have finished a program using sql server and visual studio using c# language .
I want to put the database on pc and the program that connected to that database on other PCs

I'm using this connection string in App.config :

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="MWEConnectionString" connectionString ="integrated security=yes;initial catalog=MWDB;data source=.\sqlexpress"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

Should I change server name by pc external ip address?
and according to sql server Should I use windows authentication or what?
I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should access the server by it's address by using Sql Server authentication.

Your connection string should look something like this:

```
connectionString="Data Source=192.168.0.5\SQL2008R2;Initial Catalog=MWDB;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=user;Password=password"
```

(this is just an example, your settings will probably be different).

Another example:

```
connectionString="Data Source=NAMEOFCOMPUTER\SQL2008R2;Initial Catalog=MWDB;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=user;Password=password"
```

for accessing the server by name.

You can generate a connection string for your application from Visual Studio. From `Database Explorer -> Connect to Database`

Answer (score 2):

see:
http://connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2005

http://connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2005#p1

Comment: +1 for the links. They give a wider view on the subject then just the specific problem the user has.

Comment: when I try to connect the program after setup it to remote sql server database ,it display that error:
login failed for user 'user'The user is not associated with a trusted SQL Server connection

and remote connection and sql server explorer is already running 
I don't know how to solve this problem can any body help me??