# C# Winforms - How to run exe file in other system

Tags: c#, .net, database, winforms, sql-server-2005

How to run exe file of C# Winforms app in other system or my client system?

In that Winforms application I have used SQL Server 2005 & C# for frontend ....

Now can anyone tell me, for that Winforms apps, remote connections is necessary or not? If yes then how to work on that, so I can easily run the exe file on other system also ?

I have done exe part but that file runs only on my system & that not runs on other system .

Answer (score 2):

Just publish your `.exe` using Click Once and add all the required Prerequites.
About Sql Server you have to install that on your client system and attach your database.

> 1. Goto Project Properties
> 2. Click on Publish Tab
> 3. Press Prerequisites and select all you need for your application to run like .Net Framework...
> 4. Click on the Publish Now Button

Comment: ok ...& can you tell me how to attach the database file in client system ?

Comment: & no changes in connection string ?

Comment: You can add the database in your project and change your connection string as AttachDatabaseFile

Comment: You should create a form in which you should set the Database server name and all other details about connection string and create your connection dynamically.

Comment: that makes your appliction more dynamic and easy to install

Comment: If your database in on another system then just give `DataSource=new system name\instance name` ex `DataSource=PC123\SQLEXPRESS`

Comment: can you tell me how to run exe file through some changes in connection string  & easily run in client system ?

Comment: like through remote connections ?

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to access an SQL database from another machine you will need to make sure remote connections are enabled, firewall has the right exceptions in it and the connection string points to the servers full computer name/ip address.

**EDIT**

[How to enable remote connections SQL server 2005](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/914277)

[SQL server 2005 connection strings](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2005)

[Connect to database using sql server remotely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8656066/connect-to-database-using-sql-server-remotely)

Comment: can you detailde about remote connections because when i was connect the database from server authentication login was failed , now please tell me how to enabled the remote connections from beginning ? please